# D3: Has anyone created a list view (textual) that parallels a node view (graphical)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm hooked on D3 as a way to visualize the relationships among a zillion data entities.  (Okay, maybe among a couple thousand.)

Now I want to be able to see textual information in parallel with the graphical entities -- i.e. a graphical view in one pane and a textual view in another -- so I've recently been playing with Johnny Stromberg's List.js package (http://www.listjs.com/).  It's quite responsive and does many of the things I want: sorting, filtering, etc.

But it's not D3 ;).

Ideally, I'd want something that maintains the textual list using the same binding mechanism as the graphical view in order to guarantee that the list and the display accurately track one another (i.e. using the .enter() and .exit() methods...).  And it should be easy to select a line in the list and have the selection reflected in the graphical view, and vice versa.  Filtering items in the list should cause the same filtering in the view.  Etc.

Before I dash off and write my own extensions to D3, has anyone done something like this?  Or have pointers to starting points?

Comment: I would use D3 and an html list, `ol` or `ul`. Bind your data to `li` elements. Keeps it simple, and you can go a long way with styling/transitions to spruce it up.

Comment: @EricGuan - agreed.  I plan to add methods to data(), enter() and exit() to keep the HTML text elements sync'd with the SVG graphic elements and with the underlying data objects.  But I'm still mulling the best way to get a reference back to the original object when I click on an HTML element.  Stay tuned...